# Check if a particular sheet is the activesheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to check if particular sheet is an active sheet or not?

I want particular functionality to be used for worksheet having name **Data**.

I can check if Data sheet exists or not using following code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Data")
If ws Is Nothing Then

Else
```

But how to check if Data sheet is an active sheet or not ?
is there any thing like

```
If ws Is Activesheet Then
```

**UPDATE:**

I have added following code in the one of the Class module of addin.

What i am trying to do is to manage other excel sheets from this addin. I want to call procedure `paste_cells` if the the active sheet is having name "Data".

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
MsgBox "Activate"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Data")

If ws Is ActiveSheet Then  ' if active sheet is having name Data
App.OnKey "^v", Procedure:="Paste_cell" 'paste cell is procedure i want to add when active sheet is Data
Else
App.OnKey "^v"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should

1. use error handling as the sheet may not exist
2. For an addin you would normally use ActiveWorkbook,ie

   ```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Data sheet not found"
    Else
        If ws.Name = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then
            MsgBox "Data sheet found and is active"
        Else
            MsgBox "Data sheet found but is inactive"
        End If
    End If
   ```

Comment: So if there is no 'Data' it will throw an error ? i tried but 'On Error GoTo 0' is not executing

Comment: it wont throw an error. it will execute the first `Is Nothing` branch of the IF test. Updated MsgBox code will make this clearer

Comment: @Sangram: see how error are handled in VBA >> http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can also check objects (we never know if the user has opened a workbook where the sheet has the same name):

```
Sub test()
  On Error Resume Next
  If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") Is ActiveSheet Then MsgBox ("ok")
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc36k535.aspx)

Thanks to brettdj for the reminder about the error handling.

[EDIT] Within your code:

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
MsgBox "Activate"

Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Data")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws Is Nothing and ws Is ActiveSheet Then  ' if active sheet is having name Data
  App.OnKey "^v", Procedure:="Paste_cell" 'paste cell is procedure i want to add when active sheet is Data
Else
  App.OnKey "^v"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
If Wb.ActiveSheet.Name = ws.Name Then

End If
```

Comment: I am writing this code in Excel addin, that's why i wont be able to use the ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet. right?

Comment: whats wb in the above solution?

Comment: Just the same `Wb` you used in the piece of code you gave, I believed it's active workbook

Comment: Runtime error 91: object variable or block variable not set :(

Comment: You probably just tried to use variable without setting it first. It can't be the problem of those two lines above ;) look for absence of `Set` or show the code

Comment: <removed comment re Wb which appeared incorrect. Sangram's code did use it, but the definition of Wb was not shown>

Comment: I am updating my question.sorry for confusing you.